# XUnit test for the response body content

Tags: c#, xunit.net

I am really new to XUnit and I will appreciate some help.

#### Controller

I have a really simple API  method that adds a bug comment

```
[HttpPost("{bugId}/comment")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddComment(Guid bugId, [FromBody] AddCommentForm form)
{
    return await _bugService.AddComment(bugId, form) switch
    {
        Option<BugViewModel>.Some(var bug) => Ok(bug),
        Option<BugViewModel>.None => NotFound(),
        _ => throw new InvalidOperationException()
    };
}
```

#### Service

The  `BugService` method `AddComment` looks like this

```
public async Task<Option<BugViewModel>> AddComment(Guid bugId, AddCommentForm form)
{
    if (await DbBugs.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == bugId) is { } bug)
    {
        var bugComment = new BugComment
        {
            Text = form.Text,
            Commenter = form.Commenter,
            CommentedAt = DateTime.Now,
            Bug = bug
        };

        await _dbContext.BugComments.AddAsync(bugComment);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return new Option<BugViewModel>.Some(BugViewModel.FromData(bug));
    }
    return new Option<BugViewModel>.None();
}
```

#### ViewModels

I am adding the implementation of `BugViewModel` and `BugCommentViewModel` with their static `FromData` methods

```
public class BugViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }          
    public List<BugCommentViewModel> Comments { get; set; }

    public static BugViewModel FromData(Bug bug)
    {
        return new BugViewModel
        {
            Id = bug.Id,
            Title = bug.Title,
            Description = bug.Description,               
            Comments = bug.Comments.Select(BugCommentViewModel.FromData).ToList()
        };
    }
}
```

```
public class BugCommentViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Commenter { get; set; }
    public DateTime CommentedAt { get; set; }
    
    public static BugCommentViewModel FromData(BugComment comment)
    {
        return new BugCommentViewModel
        {
            Id = comment.Id,
            Text = comment.Text,
            Commenter = comment.Commenter,
            CommentedAt = comment.CommentedAt.ToLocalTime()
        };
    }
}
```

#### Testing

The Unit Tests look like this

```
public class BugContollerTests
{
    private class Fixture
    {
        public IBugService BugService { get; } = Substitute.For<IBugService>();
        public BugController GetSut() => new BugController(BugService);
    }

    private readonly Fixture _fixture = new Fixture();

    [Fact]
    public async Task Create_ResponseBodyIsCreatedBug()
    {
        var bug = BugViewModel.FromData(FakeBug.I.Generate());
        _fixture.BugService.Create(Arg.Any<CreateBugForm>()).Returns(bug);

        var sut = _fixture.GetSut();
        var response = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<CreatedAtActionResult>(await sut.Create(new CreateBugForm()));

        Assert.Same(bug, response.Value);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task AddComment_CommentIsAddedtoViewModel()
    {
        _fixture.BugService.AddComment(Arg.Any<Guid>(), Arg.Any<AddCommentForm>()).Returns(new Option<BugViewModel>.Some(new BugViewModel()));
    
        var sut = _fixture.GetSut();
        var response = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<ObjectResult>(await sut.AddComment(Guid.Empty,new AddCommentForm()));
    
        Assert.Single(((BugViewModel) response.Value).Comments);
    }
}
```

So, the Test method I had as an example was  `Create_ResponseBodyIsCreatedBug`  but the question I have is regarding the second test method that I have created `AddComment_CommentIsAddedtoViewModel()`.

What I am trying to do is:
you see that the `BugService.AddComment` -> it adds the comment with the Bug `Guid` we have provided and basically we return `BugViewModel`  with that Comment added to the `Comments` collection.

test: that WHEN I add a `BugComment` it is returned in the `ViewModel` response and we have added exactly one Comment to the bug.
this line

```
var response = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<ObjectResult>(await sut.AddComment(Guid.Empty,new AddCommentForm()));
```

the `response.Value` is a `BugViewModel` with empty properties and the `Comment` property is empty without my inserted comment.

And on this line I get an exception as

```
Assert.Single(((BugViewModel) response.Value).Comments);
```

as the `Comments` property is `null`.

Comment: Tania, currently it is not clear what you're asking. What is your question?

Comment: Thank you Matt I have edited the question. I will appreciate any help

Comment: As it was stated by Andriy Shevchenko, the observed behaviour is normal, since you have mocked out the `BugService`'s  `AddComment`, that's why it will not call the actual implementation. In other words that test case can only assess those things which is inside the controller's `AddComment` method. So, you can assess the mapping between the `Option` and the `IActionResult`.

Comment: @TaniaMarinova As I can see you have started a bounty. What sort of help do you need? What information is missing? I think Andriy and myself have give explanation why does your test not populate the `Comments` collection. What else do you need?

Answer (score 3):

Look, at this line

```cs
_fixture.BugService.AddComment(Arg.Any<Guid>(), Arg.Any<AddCommentForm>())
    .Returns(
        new Option<BugViewModel>.Some(new BugViewModel()));
```

You setup your fake `BugService` to return an empty `BugViewModel`, which indeed would have `Comments` equal to *null* because you initialize it nowhere except `FromData`.

Use same approach you did in a first test

```cs
_fixture.BugService.AddComment(Arg.Any<Guid>(), Arg.Any<AddCommentForm>())
    .Returns(
        new Option<BugViewModel>.Some(
            BugViewModel.FromData(FakeBug.I.Generate())));
```

Or introduce a constructor

```cs
public BugViewModel(Guid id, string title, string description, List<BugCommentViewModel> comments)
{
    Id = id;
    Title = title;
    Description = description;
    Comments = comments;
}

// Comments are not NULL now
public BugViewModel(): this(Guid.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, new List<BugCommentViewModel>())
{
}
```

In addition, I don't see any purpose of unit testing a mocked dependency of `BugController` .

```cs
Assert.Single(((BugViewModel) response.Value).Comments);
```

Better move this logic to a separate `BugServiceTest` which would validate the number of comments.

One more suggestion in regards to unit testing is instead of relying on `ObjectResult`, write better three tests:

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task AddComment_CommentIsAddedtoViewModel_Success()
{
    _fixture.BugService.AddComment(Arg.Any<Guid>(), Arg.Any<AddCommentForm>())
        .Returns(
            new Option<BugViewModel>.Some(
                BugViewModel.FromData(FakeBug.I.Generate())));

    var sut = _fixture.GetSut();
    Assert.IsAssignableFrom<OkResult>(
        await sut.AddComment(Guid.Empty,new AddCommentForm()));
}

[Fact]
public async Task AddComment_BugNotFound()
{
    _fixture.BugService.AddComment(Arg.Any<Guid>(), Arg.Any<AddCommentForm>())
        .Returns(Option<BugViewModel>.None);

    var sut = _fixture.GetSut();
    Assert.IsAssignableFrom<NotFoundResult>(
        await sut.AddComment(Guid.Empty,new AddCommentForm()));
}

public async Task AddComment_ThrowsForNonsenseData()
{
    // Idk Option is value or reference type, so I use default(T)
    _fixture.BugService.AddComment(Arg.Any<Guid>(), Arg.Any<AddCommentForm>())
        .Returns(default(Option<BugViewModel>));

    var sut = _fixture.GetSut();

    await Assert.ThrowsAsync<InvalidOperationException>(
        () => sut.AddComment(Guid.Empty, new AddCommentForm()));
}
```

Tell me if that helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are mocking BugService.
You set mock to `AddComment` method and setup to return HARD CODED value.

That's why this your code is not called any more.

```
if (await DbBugs.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == bugId) is { } bug)
{
    var bugComment = new BugComment
    {
        Text = form.Text,
        Commenter = form.Commenter,
        CommentedAt = DateTime.Now,
        Bug = bug
    };

    await _dbContext.BugComments.AddAsync(bugComment);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return new Option<BugViewModel>.Some(BugViewModel.FromData(bug));
}
```

Your tests is written to check ONLY Controller.
if you want to check `BugService` too, you should NOT setup mocks for `BugService` and setup mocks to this:

```
DbBugs.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == bugId)
//and this
_dbContext.BugComments.AddAsync(bugComment);
//and this
_dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```